# Postgis 3.4 install failure - checksum verification failed

Tags: macos-monterey, postgis-installation, postgresql-16

on MacOS monterey with postgres16, I used stack builder to download and install Postgis-3.4 but I get an error at the end of each download

[image]

I have tried with another internet connection and looked online for answers or available binaries without success.

Only one old similar topic [found](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/191155/postgresql-9-4-7-postgis-2-2-1-via-stackbuilder-checksum-issue) without much assistance

I used homebrew to download and install postgis (version 3.3.4) but nothing changes when I tried to restore my database (ERROR:  extension "postgis" is not available). I presume it is because I did not install postgres through homebrew.

Comment: As a workaround I downloaded postgres.app which includes latest postgis version. I was then able to restore my database but I'm keen to solve the download's failure.